# Checkin if a specific file has access to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a responsive site that uses two includes to add a different header and footer both for mobile or desktop version.

In the desktop, everything works fine and jQuery is used as normal, but once I load the site on a simulated mobile (chrome), the same file that uses jquery doesn't seem to execute any jquery at all.

I tried checking if jquery was working or not with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('jQuery loading on mobile');
});
```

And nothing is logged in the console. However the exact same code logs it in Desktop. So then I checked if jQuery was loaded in the mobile site at all with:

```
window.onload = function() {
if (window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery is loaded
    alert("Yeah!, loading");
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
}
```

}

To which I receive a "Yeah!, loading" alert, meaning jQuery is, in fact, working on the site.

The jQuery is added in the header (in the include for mobile in this case), and if I check in the console jQuery *is* loading before my main.js function that uses it, as far as I know, if a library is included in the header before the file that uses it, it should work, right?

Is there a way to confirm if a file doesn't, for some reason, have access to an included library?

**Note:** jQuery was used in the mobile navigation to check for clicks etc, and I can see it working there, however I can't seem to use it in the body...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was a variable that was not being initialized for a function call. For some reason, this function, after crashing, was disabling jQuery for everything being called after it.

Answering myself in case someone finds this: enable the error logs in the console and try solving any errors for jQuery functions being called, if you have any.

This is how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery should perfectly load on mobile devices since their browsers also support javascript.

What functions are you calling in your script? This might help me and or others to give a clearer answer.

Comment: I know, that's the weird thing. For testing I'm just using $(document).ready(function () {, and then printing to console as showed in my question, but it doesn't work.